# Would money, capitalism and the monetary system completely disappear in a post scarcity or resource based economy?

Tags: trans-humanism, post-scarcity

Do you think it will be possible that everything will be free and people will no longer need to work if we achieve post scarcity and resource based economy?If yes, what technologies would make society achieve such a socioeconomic system?

How could such changes impact people's lives and self steem?

Comment: You are asking three quite different questions here: a) Is post-scarcity possible; b) how could that be achieved and c) how would daily life change. At the moment, the question seems to broad

Comment: as @DarthDonut point it out, this is too broad. Also, post-scarcity can't be infinite ressource of everything. Basic things like food, clothes and a car can be free, but some things like time or space will always be limited. Not everyone can be president. Not everyone can have a planet-size spaceship. Therefore, you **need** regulation, money being one of the most efficient (at least in our society)

Comment: How is it achieved? And to what degree? I don't think there is a binary on/off switch here. And it's  mandatory to point out: asking what tech needs to be developed is computer game logic. I recommend reading the wikipedia article on technology

Comment: You should read the book The Diamond Age.

Comment: As I cannot answer any more: I remember reading a book with this premise (Singularity Sky, by Charles Stross - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_Sky) featuring cornucopia machines (can make every known design from anything) and what it does to civilization.

Comment: Not only is the question too broad, it gets asked over and over - disregarding the patently obvious answer that there ain't no such thing as post-scarcity.  At best, tech just changes what's scarce: consider Silicon Valley housing prices :-)

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it, "money" is just a trade medium - something to pass back and forth while getting what you actually want via the act of trading. That said, the concept of money is pretty much guaranteed to exist in one way or another as long as trade is required.

Being in a post-scarcity society is by no means saying that trade is no longer required. I would guess that two conditions must be met for trade to become obsolete:

1. Every single human being/ cluster of humans is entirely self-sufficient;
2. No single person/ cluster of people has an excess of any resource.

This is nigh-impossible, simply because it is extremely inefficient for every human to be equipped with all the necessary tools and knowledge for survival on their own. The structure of today's world allows each person to acquire something they lack from someone else who is producing an excess, and money is just there to provide the medium. Technology is not an answer, because unless every person is able to produce that technology (e.g. a magic box) on their own without any external supplies or training, you will still have to trade for you to acquire your own box.

Since my answer is that such a change is highly improbable, I hope you don't mind that I not answer the other two parts of your question.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum you need AI.

Pets don't need money when the owners take care of them. An AI programmed to take care of us would turn us into little more than pets. All the work would be done for us so why would we need money?

Ideally if we had space travel so there is no limits on space and resources would improve it and finally matter replicators like Star Trek or at least 3d printers that can print anything.

The impact on lives and self esteem would be great. Work plays a large part in people's lives. Humanity would need a new focus. Things like art, music, science and exploration would becomes far more important.